# Model Form Fails to Validate and Post

Tags: django

Having issues with the first form validating and posting. The second form,  form2 works fine. The view code is the same structure so curious as what is causing the issue.

.is_valid() by default should validate the fields. What am I missing?

```py
# views.py

def create(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateForm(request.POST)
        form2 = CreateTimeForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('organizer-create')

        if form2.is_valid():
            form2.save()
            return redirect('organizer-create')

    else:
        form = CreateForm()
        form2 = CreateTimeForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'form2': form2,
    }

    return render(request, 'organizer/create.html', context)
```

```py
# forms.py

class CreateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'date',]
```

```py
# models.py

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    datetimecreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer-admin')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) + ", " + self.title
```

Edit 2:
Below is my template. Could a database issue cause the data not to post? How would I trouble shoot this?

```
# create.html template


{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Event Creation</legend>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Add New Time Block</legend>
    {{ form2.as_p }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I don't know what you put in your template, but I've just tested your code, and it worked fine.

Comment: If the code works on  your end and it does not work here than I assume it is possibly a database issue? Any thoughts?

Comment: I tested this again and now it is working. I am very confused as why I was having the issues before. Thank you for confirming that the code is working on your side.

Answer (score 1):

Change your views.py file as below:

```
def create(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateForm(request.POST)
    form2 = CreateTimeForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid:
        form.save()
        form2.save()
        return redirect('organizer-create')

else:
    form = CreateForm()
    form2 = CreateTimeForm()

context = {
    'form': form,
    'form2': form2,
}

return render(request, 'organizer/create.html', context)
```

Now The problem is, when the compiler compile your first if-statement that is:

```
if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('organizer-create')
```

will look and think Oh' that's correct and execute your if-statement. And then it will redirect 'organizer-create' SUCCESSFULLY. That is:

```
return redirect('organizer-create')
```

but Don't move your next if-statement.

Comment: With both forms being validated at the same time it requires them to both contain input from what I understand to meet validation. My forms are different in that only the forms that contain input are validated. Your method will not post at all if one for example form2 is empty. The goal is to validate only forms that have input and post to DB.